# How to inject @session service to custom EntityManager in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

In my config file I've defined custom Entity Manager:

```
parameters:
    doctrine.orm.entity_manager:
        class: Strict\UserBundle\Entity\Manager\MyEntityManager
```

Is the a way to inject/add @session service (I need to get access to getLocale() method) into this entity manager?
I've tried this:

```
parameters:
    doctrine.orm.entity_manager:
        class: Strict\UserBundle\Entity\Manager\MyEntityManager
        arguments: 
            session: "@session"
```

but it throws this exception:

```
InvalidArgumentException: You cannot dump a container with parameters that contain references to other services (reference to service "session" found in "/doctrine.orm.entity_manager/arguments/session").
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Parameters don't allow services as arguments, have you tried doing the same thing but using a service:

```
service:
   my.entity.manager:
      class: Strict\UserBundle\Entity\Manager\MyEntityManager
      arguments: 
        session: "@session"
```

Comment: Works great - I forgot about services :)